How to use mouse left button drag to pan on matplotlib's polar coordinate axis
it looks like the pan feature works badly on the polar axis. It does not pan the plot when I drag the left mouse button. See the image shot below:

The pan feature works OK on a matplotlib's Cartesian axis.
Here is a very simple test code for the polar plot:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

r = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * r

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
ax.plot(theta, r)
ax.set_rmax(2)
ax.set_rticks([0.5, 1, 1.5, 2])  # Less radial ticks
ax.set_rlabel_position(-22.5)  # Move radial labels away from plotted line
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_title("A line plot on a polar axis", va='bottom')


plt.show()

What I want is to pan and zoom into the polar axis, so I can see the details of the plot. Currently, the zoom is only happens around the center. So, I need a pan feature.
Any ideas? Thanks.
EDIT:
https://matplotlib.org/3.7.5/gallery/axisartist/demo_floating_axis.html
It looks like in the above example code, a float polar axis is drawn inside a Cartesian axis, I can use the mouse drag to pan the whole outer axis, but I'm not sure how to draw some curves inside the inner polar axis.

Maybe related to GH1700. A "workaround" is to use cartopy with a NorthPolarStereo projection :
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": ccrs.NorthPolarStereo()})

ax.set_extent([-180, 180, -1, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

r = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * r
lat = 90 - r * 45
lon = (np.degrees(theta) - 270) % 360

ax.plot(lon, lat, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

ax.gridlines(draw_labels=False, ylim=(0, 90))
ax.set_frame_on(False)
ax.set_title("A line plot on a polar axis", va="bottom")

plt.show()



Thanks, this is indeed a workaround, I see 0 degree, 20 degree, 40 degree and 60 degree text in your right image, but it looks like the spaces(distances) between them are not equal, I mean this is a 3D ball projection?

Polar projection distorts distances and therefore, latitudes space out from the pole (center). Try adding ax.coastlines() to see.

Hi, @Timeless, thanks for the help, I think I have found a solution by chatGPT, you can see my answer I just minutes ago using the floating axis method. But I need to use another axis named ax2 in the code, I'm not sure why.

I think I have at least find an answer, which is the code derived from the python's floating axis example: https://matplotlib.org/3.7.5/gallery/axisartist/demo_floating_axis.html
Here is the code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist.angle_helper as angle_helper
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist import GridHelperCurveLinear, HostAxes
from matplotlib.projections import PolarAxes
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.grid_finder import MaxNLocator, DictFormatter
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

def curvelinear_test2(fig):
    """Polar projection, but in a rectangular box."""
    tr = Affine2D().scale(np.pi / 180, 1) + PolarAxes.PolarTransform()

    extreme_finder = angle_helper.ExtremeFinderCycle(
        20, 20,
        lon_cycle=360,
        lat_cycle=None,
        lon_minmax=None,
        lat_minmax=(0, np.inf)
    )

    grid_locator1 = MaxNLocator(6)
    tick_formatter1 = DictFormatter(dict(zip(range(0, 360, 45), ['0', '45', '90', '135', '180', '225', '270', '315'])))

    grid_helper = GridHelperCurveLinear(
        tr,
        extreme_finder=extreme_finder,
        grid_locator1=grid_locator1,
        tick_formatter1=tick_formatter1
    )

    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(axes_class=HostAxes, grid_helper=grid_helper)

    # Now create floating axis
    ax1.axis["lat"] = axis = ax1.new_floating_axis(0, 60)
    axis.label.set_text(r"$\theta = 60^{\circ}$")
    axis.label.set_visible(True)

    ax1.axis["lon"] = axis = ax1.new_floating_axis(1, 6)
    axis.label.set_text(r"$r = 6$")

    ax1.set_aspect(1.)
    ax1.set_xlim(-10, 10)
    ax1.set_ylim(-10, 10)

    ax1.grid(True)

    # Define the data for the plot
    r = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)
    theta = 2 * np.pi * r

    # Create an auxiliary axes for the polar data
    ax2 = ax1.get_aux_axes(tr)

    # Plot the line on the auxiliary axes with the correct transformation
    ax2.plot(theta * 180 / np.pi, r, color='red', label='Polar plot')

    # Create a meshgrid for the image
    theta_mesh, r_mesh = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100), np.linspace(0, 2, 50))
    z = np.sin(3 * theta_mesh) * r_mesh

    # Plot the meshgrid image on the auxiliary axes
    mesh = ax2.pcolormesh(theta_mesh * 180 / np.pi, r_mesh, z, shading='auto', cmap='viridis', alpha=0.75)

    # Create a divider for the existing axes instance
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
    # Append axes to the right of ax1, with 5% width of ax1
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.1)

    # Add a color bar for the meshgrid image
    cbar = fig.colorbar(mesh, cax=cax)
    cbar.set_label('Color scale')

    # Show the legend
    ax2.legend()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
curvelinear_test2(fig)
plt.show()

The code is mainly generated by ChatGPT, and I asked ChatGPT several times to modify the code to get the final result, here is the result image shot:

You can see in the image, the ax1 is the floating axis, and it later create a new ax2 which use the Transform tr, and I later draw some curves and a mesh color image on the ax2, it seems to work well.
I'm not fully understand the code, and but the most code is from the float axis example code. I hope some python expert can help to explain the code. Thanks.
